# Finding archetype for a Maven Google App Engine project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, maven-archetype

I'm creating a new Java project for Google App Engine using Eclipse and the m2eclipse plugin. When creating a new Maven project Eclipse doesn't find the archetype

> com.google.appengine.archetypes:guestbook-archetype.

I should probably be adding a new catalog, but which one? (A google search didn't help). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try searching for guestbook-archetype instead of the full path.  You should see it in the list that Eclipse displays.