# Generate a pom.xml file using App Engine and Maven

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, web-applications, pom.xml

I'm using Google App Engine for Eclipse and also Git.

First I've created my "helloworld" project with Eclipse and GAE plugin

Then I've created a repository that I've cloned on my Google server machine.

Only problem is my project don't have any `pom.xml` and I think that's making bug the whole process when I enter `$ mvn appengine:run`.

Is there a way to create a `pom.xml` file with `mvn` CLI? Do you think that's the only problem I have.

Here is my error log:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project
>   and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mo
>   jo] available from the repositories [local
>   (/home/Jsmith/.m2/repository), central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [He lp 1]

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse allows to convert a project to maven, try
right click on the project name > Configure > Convert to Maven Project

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Maven project (including the POM) from a template called [Archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) in Maven terminology:

> In short, Archetype is a Maven project templating toolkit. An archetype is defined as an *original pattern or model from which all other things of the same kind are made*. The name fits as we are trying to provide a system that provides a consistent means of generating Maven projects.

Comment: so I can't use google app engine plugin anymore. sorry but I'm really really new to this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @JSmith See [Finding archetype for a Maven Google App Engine project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13911829/1744774).

Comment: okay I'll do more research and see what I can do. I'm really lost sorry.